# Detect number of CPUs installed

Tags: ruby

I already found a solution for "Most unixes" via `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, but a pure-Ruby solution would be nicer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am currently using this, which covers all os.
https://github.com/grosser/parallel/blob/master/lib/parallel.rb#L63

```
  def self.processor_count
    case RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
    when /darwin9/
      `hwprefs cpu_count`.to_i
    when /darwin/
      ((`which hwprefs` != '') ? `hwprefs thread_count` : `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`).to_i
    when /linux/
      `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`.to_i
    when /freebsd/
      `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.to_i
    when /mswin|mingw/
      require 'win32ole'
      wmi = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://")
      cpu = wmi.ExecQuery("select NumberOfCores from Win32_Processor") # TODO count hyper-threaded in this
      cpu.to_enum.first.NumberOfCores
    end
  end
```

Comment: If you copy-and-paste this method out of Parallel, you'll need to also pull the `hwprefs_available` method as well -- or better, require the gem and call `Parallel.processor_count`.

Comment: The `Parallel` library has been updated and the `processor_count` method is now in
https://github.com/grosser/parallel/blob/master/lib/parallel/processor_count.rb

Comment: Note that NumberOfCores does only give you the number of physical cores of one CPU in the system. You have to multiply that by the number of CPUs (see Konstantin Haases answer below)...

Answer (score 52):

As of Ruby version 2.2.3, the [`etc`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html) module in Ruby's stdlib offers an [`nprocessors`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html#method-c-nprocessors) method which returns the number of processors. The caveat to this, is that if ruby is relegated to a subset of CPU cores, `Etc.nprocessors` will only return the number of cores that Ruby has access to. Also, as [seanlinsley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2651774/seanlinsley) pointed out, this will only return virtual cores instead of physical cores, which may result in a disparity in the expected value.

```
require 'etc'
p Etc.nprocessors #=> 4
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns virtual cores instead of physical cores, and there isn't a method on `Etc` to get physical cores.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @seanlinsley. I've edited my answer to make that clear.

Comment: This works great for me. Definitely returns virtual cores but that's what you want in some cases. For example, I have a quad-core hyperthreaded MacBook Pro and this returns `8`.

Comment: In my usecase: deciding how many threads to spawn in a threadpool in order to maximize cpu usage, this number does the trick. Thx!

Comment: Does it support windows?

Answer (score 45):

EDIT: Now rails ships with concurrent-ruby as a dependency so it's probably the best solution;

```
$ gem install concurrent-ruby
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'concurrent'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Concurrent.processor_count
=> 8
irb(main):003:0> Concurrent.physical_processor_count
=> 4
```

see http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/master/Concurrent.html for more info. Because it does both physical and logical cores, it's better than the inbuilt `Etc.nprocessors`.

and here is the previous answer;

```
$ gem install facter
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'facter'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> puts Facter.value('processors')['count']
4
=> nil
irb(main):003:0>
```

This [facter gem](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter) is the best if you want other facts about the system too, it's not platform specific and designed to do this exact thing.

UPDATE: updated to include Nathan Kleyn's tip on the api change.

Comment: nice solution, ill check it out, since i am working on a public library i did not want to add an extra dependency for something this trivial

Comment: For those coming here and wondering why `Facter.sp_number_processors` doesn't work in the latest version, try `Facter.processorcount` instead.

Comment: `Facter.processorcount` says my Macbook Air's dual-core Intel i5 has 4 processors. `#sp_number_processors` says 2, correctly. You can see all the available facts for your machine with `Facter.list`.

Comment: I am unable to get the facter gem to work on Windows running Rails 4. At first: cannot load win32/dir but 'gem install win32-dir fixed that. Now: cannot load windows/system_info and I can't find an appropriate gem to get around that. The new facter docs don't help.

Comment: @ryanttb, there has been dramatic changes in Facter API. Moreover, now that Ruby 1.9+ is ubiquitous, there’s no need to include RubyGems explicitly. I’ve suggested an edit, but in case you need it, try `Facter.value('processors')['count']`.

Answer (score 11):

with JRuby you can check it with the following Java code:

```
 Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();   
 int numberOfProcessors = runtime.availableProcessors();
```

Comment: I've voted this one up particularly because of the implicit point that with JRuby you can actually use those extra cores with Ruby's Thread class!  Might it be worth adding this version of the example too?
#!/usr/bin/jruby
include Java
puts "You have #{java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors} cores"

Answer (score 11):

Here is an implementation for Linux, OSX, Windows and BSD: https://gist.github.com/1009994

Source code:

```
module System
  extend self
  def cpu_count
    return Java::Java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors if defined? Java::Java
    return File.read('/proc/cpuinfo').scan(/^processor\s*:/).size if File.exist? '/proc/cpuinfo'
    require 'win32ole'
    WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_ComputerSystem").NumberOfProcessors
  rescue LoadError
    Integer `sysctl -n hw.ncpu 2>/dev/null` rescue 1
  end
end

System.cpu_count # => 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Surely if you can `cat` it, you can open, read and close it using the standard features of the language without resorting to a `system()`-type call.

You may just need to detect what platform you're on dynamically and either:

- use the `/proc/cpuinfo` "file" for Linux; or
- communicate with WMI for Windows.

That last line can use:

```
require 'win32ole'
wmi = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://")
info = wmi.ExecQuery ("select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
```

Then use info's [NumberOfProcessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102.aspx) item.

Comment: Or possibly NumberOfProcessors. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I hoped it would be something easy, for now I will skip this feature :)

Answer (score 4):

In linux you can also use `nproc`, which is cleaner that the other subshell-based solutions here. I wanted vagrant to give the same number of CPUs to the virtual machine as the host has. I added this to `Vagrantfile`:

```
vb.cpus = `nproc`.to_i
```

Comment: This also works for MacOS

Answer (score 3):

I tried using `Facter` but found it a bit slow. I tried `system` gem and found it a lot faster. It is also very easy to use: `System::CPU.count`.

Answer (score 1):

on Mac:

thiago-pradis-macbook:~ tchandy$ hwprefs cpu_count

2

Answer (score 1):

@grosser:

```
when /linux/  
  `grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo`.to_i
```

http://www.partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat
http://www.partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#wc

Answer (score 0):

I found something recently that may have to be taken into consideration.  You can deactivate processors (take them offline), and then facter processorcount (plus some of the other methods above) gives the wrong result.  You can count processor lines in /proc/cpuinfo, as long as you do it correctly.  If you just populate an array with index numbers of the procs, if you have gaps in the procs (as in, procs 0,1,2,10,11,12 are active, all others to 20 say are inactive), it will automatically spring indexes 3-9 into existence (sort of), at least Array#size will report 13 in that case.  You would have to do #compact to get the number of active processors.  However, if you want total processors, perhaps better is looking at /sys/devices/system/cpu[0-9], and count that up.  That will give you the total number of processors, but not how many (or which ones) are active.

Just something to think about.  I trying to put through a patch to facter to add an activeprocessorcount and totalprocessorcount fact.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of @grosser's and @paxdiablo's answer, since on my system (winxp) win32_computersystem doesn't have any processor info; this works though:

```
require 'win32ole'
wmi = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://")
info = wmi.ExecQuery ("select NumberOfCores from Win32_processor")
puts info.to_enum.first.NumberOfCores
```

To see what's available on your system, run this from [powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd772288) (i used 1.0 in this case):

```
Get-WmiObject -list
```

(might want to pipe to grep if you've got cygwin installed)