# Is there any way to find the number of CPU cores in MRI Ruby (perhaps using a C extension)?

Tags: ruby, multiprocessing, multicore

In JRuby, you can just use `java.lang.Runtime.get_runtime.available_processors`. Is there anything available for MRI, perhaps using a gem implemented in C?

In a future release of Ruby, it would be nice to see this information available as a automatically defined top-level constant, like `RUBY_PLATFORM` and `RUBY_VERSION`.

Comment: this maybe is too late but your answer is [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891537/detect-number-of-cpus-installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far there isn't. But you can either use `parallel` gem or take a look how it [figures out the number of cores](https://github.com/grosser/parallel/blob/master/lib/parallel/processor_count.rb).